# Transforming Raw Sql to Laravel equolent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have written this SQL code

```
SELECT drugs.*, COUNT(*) as 'views' from drugs INNER JOIN drug_seen on drugs.id = drug_seen.drug_id GROUP BY drugs.id order by views ASC
```

And now I am trying to write in in the Laravel equolent but I am facing some troubles.
This is what I have tried

```
$drugs = Drug::select(DB::raw('drugs.*,count(*) as views'))
                    ->join('drug_seen', 'drugs.id', 'drug_seen.drug.id')
                    ->groupBy('drug.id')->orderByRaw('views');
```

I am having errors like column not found i think the code is not written properly

Drug class

```
class Drug extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

...
...
...

public function drugVisits()
{
     return $this->hasMany(DrugSeen::class);
}
```

Comment: If you actually want to use Eloquent you'll have to use your `Drug` model and the Eloquent APIs, this code is still using the low-level DB API's too much and raw queries. Could you share your `Drug` model class and elaborate on your intentions? It's hard to know what you want from just an SQL query.

Comment: @Thymeleaf, which error you are getting, can you show full error

Comment: Does the sql you wrote works? Because i think it will throw error

Comment: @workservice yeah the sql works perfectly fine

Comment: @YasinPatel this is the error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'drug_seen.drug.id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0):

Hop this will solve your problem.

```
$drugs = Drug::with('drugVisits')->get();

$drugs->count(); //for total records in drugs table.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo error in `join` instead on `drug_id` you use `drug.id`

Try this:

```
$drugs = Drug::select(DB::raw('drugs.*,count(*) as views'))
                  ->join('drug_seen', 'drugs.id', 'drug_seen.drug_id')
                  ->groupBy('drugs.id')->orderByRaw('views');
          }
```

Comment: Tried this it is throwing  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'drug.id' in 'group statement'

Comment: updated answer, Bcs you don't have drug.id it is drugs.id

Comment: I am having diffrent errors can we go to the chat ?

Comment: Its like another query it is exceuting before this I think they are conflicting with each other

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use `join()` you're leaving Eloquent and entering `Query\Builder`, losing the benefits of Model configurations in the process. And `with()` eager-loads aren't the answer, if you're looking to filter the results by *both* tables. What you want is `whereHas()`.

Also, as far as your grouping and count manipulation there, I think you're looking more for Collection handling than SQL groups.

```
$drugModel = app(Drugs::class);
$results = $drugModel->whereHas('drugVisits')->with('drugVisits')->get();
$organizedResults = $results
    ->groupBy($drugModel->getKey())
    ->sortyBy(function (Drugs $drugRecord) {
        return $drugRecord->drugVisits->count();
    });
```

If you want to have a 'views' property that carries the count in the root-level element, it would look like this:

```
$drugModel = app(Drugs::class);
$results = $drugModel->whereHas('drugVisits')->with('drugVisits')->get();
$organizedResults = $results
    ->groupBy($drugModel->getKey())
    ->map(function (Drugs $drugRecord) {
        $drugRecord->views = $drugRecord->drugVisits->count();
        return $drugRecord;
    });
    ->sortyBy('views');
```